# Can I connect a capacitor to a power source directly?

Tags: capacitor

Can I connect a capacitor to a DC power source so the positive (+) power terminal attaches to the + lead on the capacitor, and the negative (-) power terminal to the - lead on the capacitor?  Would this cause a fire and act like a short between the positive and negative lead of the power source, or does the capacitor fill up, then act like a resistor and stop the current flow?

Comment: It is fine to connect them when the output voltage of the supply and the voltage across the capacitor are close to each other. If they are not close to each other, you may get a spark at the moment you connect them. The spark can suprise you with the amount of energy it delivers. It can cause small pieces of metal to erode from the contacts, and make a loud noise. Perhaps you could even get a very small burn on your finger or something if it is very close to the spark.

Comment: The easiest thing is to discharge the cap with a resistor, set the supply output to zero volts (or turn it off) and then connect the capacitor when both are at 0 V. Then you can turn on the supply and hopefully it will come up OK with the capacitor there. Lab supplies generally seem to do fine. Other supplies may not like the capacitor because of startup over-current. But in any event at least there will be no spark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the correct polarity.  Cause a fire?  Almost certainly not unless the power supply was designed with criminal negligence and the capacitor is huge.  You will probably see a spark if you are connecting the capacitor to a live supply.  The capacitor will charge rapidly at a rate determined by the maximum current of your power supply, the ESR of the capacitor, and any parasitic L/R, whereupon it will act as an open circuit, with no further current flow.  Depending on your power supply, you might trip the overcurrent protection.

Comment: Thanks - I know its a basic question, but I do not yet understand the basic properties of components.  I am not expecting nefarious intentions (like a power supply designed with criminal negligence), just trying to understand what a capacitor is and how it responds to basic circuits.  Sounds like the capacitor can simply sit as a buffer on a power rail (again, assuming the math is good - i.e., voltage, current, etc.).  I am playing wit 5v and 1000uf capacitors.  Nothing big.

Comment: If it is a tantalum capacitor or otherwise can't handle the currents or voltages, you can't say nothing happens.

Comment: Like @justme said, make sure that the voltage of your capacitor is less than the voltage you're applying.  Capacitors are used for many different purposes depending on the circuit and environment and that's where knowing the difference between different types comes in.

Comment: The voltage of the capacitor states 16v.  I assume that means it can handle input up to 16v.  @vir - you mentioned the voltage of the capacitor needs to be less than the 5v I am applying.  Forgive me, I'm completely ignorant, but that seems backwards.  Is that because at least 16v is needed to fully operate the capacitor?  If so, how much voltage could I apply if it is rated at 16v?

Comment: @barrypicker: I think vir got a bit mixed up.  The rated voltage of the capacitor MUST be greater than the supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBennett!

Comment: @barrypicker High current caused by connecting uncharged capacitors to power supplies is such a common problem it has a name: "inrush current". Almost everything you plug into anything has inrush current, and it only lasts for a few milliseconds, so it doesn't cause any fire - however, if not taken into account in the design, it might cause a microprocessor to reboot for example.

Comment: @PeterBennett To be safe in this case, the capacitor's rated voltage needs to be more than _twice_ the supply voltage, doesn't it? Given the inductance in the capacitor leads and everything else, connecting a capacitor to a 12 V power supply could theoretically briefly charge it up to 24 V. I'm not sure if what I'm saying is right, though.

Comment: Yes correct, I got mixed up there.  Thanks @PeterBennett.

Answer (score 6):

The capacitor would need to handle the voltage from power supply. And both the cap and the supply must handle the surge current to charge the cap.

So it depends on the capacitor type.

If it is a capacitor that can't handle the voltage or current, or the supply can't handle the current, something may get damaged.

If cap is at different voltage, it will be a short circuit when connected and when it reaches supply voltage it will be an open circuit.

Some DC supplies, depending on their type and consltruction, have limits on what amount of capacitance is allowed on the output. Too high or too low capacitance values may make the DC supply unstable.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the voltage ratings of the capacitor and the power supply - and how much current the power supply can deliver.

If the the power supply voltage is higher than the rated voltage of the capacitor, then the capacitor will be damaged.  Some capacitors will fail and short circuit when you exceed the voltage rating.  If the power supply can deliver enough current, then the capacitor may explode or catch fire.

If the power supply voltage is lower than the capacitor voltage rating, then the capacitor will "fill up" and stop drawing current.

---

Tantalum capacitors are known to "vent with flames" when their voltage ratings are exceeded:

[image]

<sub>[Youtube source.](https://youtu.be/rVYGZ2hFUsw)</sub>

Aluminum electrolytic capacitors tend to pop:

[image]

<sub>[Youtube source.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sW0a9d_vWoc)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

At the instant that you connect the capacitor to the EMF, there is essentially a short in the wires between the capacitor and the EMF; a displacement current will flow from the EMF to the capacitor with negligible resistance. However, once the charge moved by this displacement current matches VC, the displacement current will stop (technically, the current decays exponentially to zero, but we can treat it as having a finite duration for most purposes), and the total power carried by this charge will be V^2 C/2. So if you have a 9V battery connected to a 1μF capacitor, that will be 81μJ. This will be enough to get a spark, but unless you have something highly flammable in the vicinity, it won't start a fire.

Comment: Thanks @Accumulation - very interesting details.  The behavior of a capacitor is curious and obviously helpful.